# module 'torch' has no attribute 'frombuffer' in Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

```
data_root = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "data")
transform = transforms.Compose(
[
 transforms.ToTensor(),
 transforms.Normalize([0.5], [0.5]),
]
)
fashion_mnist_dataset = FashionMNIST(data_root, download = True, train = True, transform = transform)
```

Error Message

> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision/datasets/mnist.py in read_sn3_pascalvincent_tensor(path, strict)
> 524     # we need to reverse the bytes before we can read them with torch.frombuffer().
> 525     needs_byte_reversal = sys.byteorder == "little" and num_bytes_per_value > 1
> --> 526     parsed = torch.frombuffer(bytearray(data), dtype=torch_type, offset=(4 * (nd + 1)))
> 527     if needs_byte_reversal:
> 528         parsed = parsed.flip(0)
>
> AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'frombuffer'

what can i do for this err in Colab

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code in my Google Colab by adding the codes (to import the libraries) below, but it works well without errors.

```
import os
from torchvision import transform
from torchvision.datasets import FashionMNIST
```

I used

- torchvision   0.13.0+cu113
- google-colab   1.0.0
- Runtime GPU   (when I set "None," it also works)

Do you get errors when you also use the same codes above? Do you use another versions?